# ProGuard (sbt-proguard) : "target/scala-2.10/proguard/merged/LICENSE" directory not merging

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard, sbt-proguard

I am getting the following error.

```
[info] Merging inputs before proguard...
[error] /my/project/target/scala-2.10/proguard/merged/LICENSE (Is a directory)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to merge all inputs. Merge strategies can be used to resolve conflicts.

...

[error] (proguard:mergedInputs) Failed to merge all inputs. Merge strategies can be used to resolve conflicts.
```

([More details](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard/issues/15)...)

And I've tried the followings...

```
ProguardKeys.merge in Proguard := true
ProguardKeys.mergeStrategies in Proguard += ProguardMerge.discard("license/.*".r)
```

and

```
ProguardKeys.merge in Proguard := true
ProguardKeys.mergeStrategies in Proguard += ProguardMerge.append("license")
```

None of above are working. Are there anything wrong about the merge strategies?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this `ProguardKeys.mergeStrategies in Proguard += ProguardMerge.first("LICENSE.*".r)`. This thing is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Zyoma Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProguardKeys.mergeStrategies in Proguard += ProguardMerge.rename("LICENSE.*".r)
```

rename() did the job~!